# Symfony upgrade 2.0 -> 2.3, @Method not working

Tags: symfony, methods, annotations, request

I'll start from the action code that I wrote in controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\MaskBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

/* ... */

 /**
 * @Route("/create", name="case_create")
 * @Template("NubusCaseBundle:LawCase:new.html.twig")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function createAction(Request $request) { /* */ }
```

Unfortunatelly, when I POST (!) data to it, I receive this answer:

```
No route found for "POST /case/create": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)
```

Ive also tried defining Method this way:

```
* @Method("POST")
```

When I remove Method annotation everything works fine, but that's not what we're going to do, is it?

I'm upgrading the app from 2.0 to 2.3, I created blank project, moved the src dir, moved some config files, created composer.json and used it, and fixed some bugs. Am I missing something or it is a bug that needs to be fixed?

Comment: can you show your routing.yml? :)

Comment: I already resolved the issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I didnt injected the RequestContext to my own Router class:

services.xml:

```
<argument type="service" id="router.request_context"></argument>
```

So my router saw:

```
GET /
```

Instead of:

```
POST /case/create
```

Because of constructor that by default takes method GET and path /.

Mr. Gideon, you're not paying attention!